# Retrieve SQL string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to get rows from my data where for example,`[column name] = "Offer-25%"` or `"download-50%"`.

The problem is when I put this particular value in it doesn't return a result when I know this value exists.

But if I write `[Column name] = 'In progress'` it returns a result.

Is there something that I can do in order to retrieve data values for the prior? Is there some other function to use to get strings w/character like this one ex. `"offer-25%"`

I should also add that the data type is `VARCHAR(16777216)`

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: What DBMS are you actually using? Neither sql server nor mysql supports a varchar that large.

Comment: square bracket around the column name suggests Sql Server rather than MySql, but not definitively (could just be used as an example). Still, I'm gonna make the edit, and if I'm wrong that's the consequence of not tagging the question right in the first place. Play silly games, win silly prizes.

Comment: A [mre] with sample data, desired results and your full attempt would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You **MUST** use single quotes instead of double quotes for the strings.

This will work:

```
[column name] = 'Offer-25'
```

This will **NOT WORK**:

```
[column name] = "Offer-25%"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Yes I used the wrong quotes in this example but my issue is retriving the entire string 'Offer-25%'. 'Offer-25' doesn't return any results

Comment: Did you want a `LIKE` matching instead of `=`?